# how to show user google search engine result in a browser project

Tags: swift, uiwebview

I am implementing a browser with `UIWebView` with swift for iPhone, iPad. all works fine but the problem is that when users type wrong or not completed URL of their favorite website, it seems that it crashed and dose not render anything. so I want to do somehow if browser could not find the requested page, then it automatically search that exact word  on google search engine and shows the result in browser. 
here is my codes for this part if needed. 
Appreciate any help

```
 func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    //let urlString:String = urlTextField.text!
    var urlString: String = urlTextField.text!

    if !urlString.starts(with: "http://") && !urlString.starts(with: "https://") {
        urlString = "http://\(urlString)"
    }

    let url:URL = URL(string: urlString)!
    let urlRequest:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.load(urlRequest)

    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    let path: String = url.path
    let ext: String = URL(fileURLWithPath: path ).pathExtension
    print(ext as Any)

    return true

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a check to verify if your urlString contains `www` and if not you can set "https://www.google.com/search?q=" url with your text:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    guard let urlString = urlTextField.text else { return true }

    if urlString.starts(with: "http://") || urlString.starts(with: "https://") {
        loadUrl(urlString)
    } else if urlString.contains(“www”) {
        loadUrl("http://\(urlString)")   
    } else { 
        searchTextOnGoogle(urlString)
    }

    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    //...

    return true
} 

func loadUrl(_ urlString: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url) 
    webView.load(urlRequest)
}

func searchTextOnGoogle(_ text: String) {
    // check if text contains more then one word separated by space 
    let textComponents = text.components(separatedBy: " ") 

    // we replace space with plus to validate the string for the search url
    let searchString = textComponents.joined(separator: "+") 

    guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + searchString) else { return }

    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url) 
    webView.load(urlRequest)
}
```

Comment: thank you very very much, it seems very helpful. but the above code has two errors in these lines.  `guard let urlString = urlTextField.text else { return }. Non-void function should return a value` and `func loadUrl(_ urlString) {.  Parameter requires an explicit type`. is it possible to help me in these codes?

Comment: @nedaDerakhshesh Sorry, my distraction ;) I have edited my answer.

Comment: @Francesco Deliro Thanks

Comment: @FrancescoDeliro thank you very very much. it solved and works completely fine.  thank you 1000..000 times

Comment: @user2296278 thank you very much too for your previous helps and codes.